# mysql GROUP CONCAT not returning values

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, aggregate-functions, where-clause

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(o.order_disc + o.order_disc_vat) AS manualsale
FROM
    orders o
WHERE
    o.order_flag IN (0 , 2, 3)
        AND o.order_status = '1'
        AND (o.assign_sale_id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(id AS SIGNED)) AS ids FROM users WHERE team_id = 92))
        AND DATE(o.payment_on) = DATE(NOW())
```

above query return null when i run this query in terminal

When i use subquery below it returns data

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(id AS SIGNED)) AS ids FROM users WHERE team_id = 92)
```

above query returns

```
'106,124,142,179'
```

and when i run my first query like below

```
SELECT 
    SUM(o.order_disc + o.order_disc_vat) AS manualsale
FROM
    orders o
WHERE
    o.order_flag IN (0 , 2, 3)
        AND o.order_status = '1'
        AND (o.assign_sale_id IN (106,124,142,179))
        AND DATE(o.payment_on) = DATE(NOW())
```

it return me value.
Why it is not working with subquery please help

Comment: What datatype is o.assign_sale_id

Comment: o. assign_sale_id is of  int datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not do what you want:

```
AND (o.assign_sale_id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(id AS SIGNED)) AS ids FROM users WHERE team_id = 92))
```

This compares a single value against a comma-separated list of values, so it never matches (unless there is just one row in users for the given team).

You *could* phrase this as:

```
AND assign_sale_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE team_id = 92)
```

But this would probably be more efficently expressed with `exists`:

```
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users u WHERE u.team_id = 92 AND u.id = o.assign_sale_id)
```

Side note: I would also recommend rewriting this condition:

```
AND DATE(o.payment_on) = DATE(NOW())
```

To the following, which can take advantage of an index:

```
AND o.payment_on >= current_date AND o.payment_on < current_date + interval 1 day
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB assign_sale_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE team_id = 92) i used this i dont how can i do this silly mistake, thank for your help mate